Getting error while start nginx in Docker in Gitlab CI
The error occurs while running deploy job in Gitlab CI(docker:dind executor, gitlab runner runs in docker). On local machine everything works fine.
fine.
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/builds/daniskazan/goboards-backend/nginx/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": create mount destination for /etc/nginx/nginx.conf mount: cannot mkdir in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cbcfa805f4e22d4b77cee331b5aee81ff2c8bb240fdd266cdce1d4c8bdc9642a/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
My docker-compose.yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    container_name: nginx-${ENVIRONMENT:-local}
    ports:
      - "80:80"


There is one thing you have missed. Mounted file should already exist inside docker host before mounting. Otherwise docker creates a directory instead.
So you need to create nginx.conf empty file before mounting

Running  ls -l ./nginx/nginx.conf shows valid output, meaning that file exists
